# How to call this wordcount function using the meteorhacks:npm package?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, meteor, npm

I installed [meteorhacks/npm](https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm) in order to use the [Wordcount](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wordcount) package in my Meteor app.

However, I can't get my method working.

client

```
  getWordcount = function getWordcount(words, callback) {
    Meteor.call('getWordcount', words, callback);
  }

console.log(getWordcount('hello world')); // testing
```

server

```
  Meteor.methods({
    'getWordcount': function getWordcount(words) {
      var WordcountApi = Meteor.npmRequire('wordcount');
      var wordcount = new WordcountApi({
          version: "1.1.1"
      });

      var words = Async.runSync(function(done) {
        wordcount.words, function(err, data) {
          done(null, data);
        }
      });

      return words.result;
    }
  });
```

I'm returning an error message in my console that says:

"Error invoking Method 'getWordcount': Internal server error [500]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion

Client

```
// call meteor method and catch err or results in a callback function
Meteor.call('getWordcount', 'hello world', function(err, results){
    if(err) console.error(err);
    else    console.log(results);
});
```

Server

```
  Meteor.methods({
      'getWordcount': function getWordcount(words) {
          check(words, String);
          var wordcount = Meteor.npmRequire('wordcount');
          return wordcount(words);
      }
  });
```